# How to automate Mobile App with wired system using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, application-software-testing

I have a system connected with LAN cable. Now I want to record the test of a Mobile Application (Android and iOS), and then see the performance of the app using JMeter.

I tried with connecting the device via USB to the system, changed the WiFi Proxy to Manual, added the system's IP Address and Started recording the Test. But nothing was showing in the tool. I am doubting about the Proxy settings itself, as the device is not connected with the same Internet as the system, so changing the Proxy of another WiFi won't help.

So, now what are the steps to do it?

Answer (score 3):

1. The most straightforward option is installing your application into [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) or [iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html), this way the "virtual" handheld device will be using your machine's Internet connection and you will be able to capture the traffic with JMeter
2. You can go for so called "reverse USB tethering", refer the following guides:

   - [How to use Windows' internet on Android phone through USB cable](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-windows-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable)
   - [iPhone Connecting to Internet Using Windows PC’s Network through USB Cable](https://www.systutorials.com/iphone-connecting-internet-using-windows-pc-network-through-usb-cable/)
3. If your application backend is publicly available the fastest and the easiest way would be using a 3rd-party recording solution like [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder)